# EF Core 3.1 - Mapping 0..1 relationship where dependent has shared PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have this situation where I have been unable to correctly fetch my dependent class using an Include in EF Core 3.1 when fetching the principal. This situation might be a little different to MS's docs as in the dependent class the PK and FK are on the same field, FileDefinitionId

Despite all of the code below, fileDefinition.FileImportDefinition is null.

Is there something I have missed? I've been following [Microsoft's docs on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one)

```
            fileDefinition = context.FileDefinitions
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.FileImportDefinition)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.FileDefinitionId == fileDefinitionId);
```

Principal

```
public partial class FileDefinition
{
    public long FileDefinitionId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual FileImportDefinition FileImportDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

Dependent

```
public partial class FileImportDefinition
{
    public long FileDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual FileDefinition FileDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelBuilding - FileDefinition (principal)

```
            entity.HasOne(d => d.FileImportDefinition)
                .WithOne(p => p.FileDefinition)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .HasForeignKey<FileImportDefinition>(d => d.FileDefinitionId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_FileImportDefinitions_FileDefinitions")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Comment: *"as in the dependent class the PK and FK are on the same field"* Actually this (called shared PK association) is the default for EF Core one-to-one relationships. Your example works for me (EFC 3.1.19, SqlServer) - the navigation property is loaded as expected. You have some conflicting / non applicable configurations for this type of relationship (`IsRequired(false)`, `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull`) which normally are ignored by EFC, but it's safer to not rely on that, i.e. remove the first (PK is always required), and change the second to `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, would definitely mark this as the answer if I could. One other issue I noticed was that my class was using System.Data.Entity over Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore for the context LINQ methods (EF6 > EFCore migration project)